# What's wrong with my code for Google Code Jam Round 1B 2013 "Osmos"?

Tags: java, algorithm

I've passed the sample input, and also some input which I decided to strike up (even the extreme cases), but I don't know why I got "Incorrect." Also, ignore the `quickSort()` call, I've implemented it and it works fine. In case you need an overview, here's the link to the problem: https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/2434486/dashboard#s=p0&a=0
I even checked the editorial and I don't know where I missed.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = in.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        int size = in.nextInt();
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int ops = 0;
        int[] sizes = new int[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            sizes[j] = in.nextInt();
        }
        quickSort(sizes);
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (sizes[j] < size) {
                size += sizes[j];
            } else {
                int newSize = (size * 2) - 1;
                if (sizes[j] < newSize) {
                    size = newSize;
                }
                ops++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Case #" + (i + 1) + ": " + ops);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So lets run through the logic of the problem you are trying to solve.

You have two options:

- Remove a mote
- Add a mote

Currently you are only adding motes, represented by `newSize = (size * 2) - 1`.  Effectively doubling (almost) the size of your mote each time.

What if the new size of your mote is still insufficient to capture the mote represented by the current `j` iteration in your loop?  You need to make the choice again of adding another mote, or removing that mote.

So lets say your mote has a size of 2 and the other motes have sizes of `1, 1, 3, 5, 8, 1000, 1001`.  You could either continue to add lots of motes until your mote can absorb `1000` and `1001`, or you could just remove the two that are absurdly large.

With this revelation at seems that iteration will not always lead to the most optimal answer.  At each step each choice you make is another possible path that could *potentially* hold the answer, but you want to find the decision path that leads to the least amount of operations.  Its as if you want to follow all possible paths and then choose from the best solution found.

Luckily there are plenty of resources online about this.  I recommend googling `pathfinding` and `pathfinding algorithms`.  There is a bit to learn on the topic, but it's all interesting and fun.

Goodluck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've noticed something, though. I have two options - add a mote (requires one operation). If adding one mote won't work, then I will still need one operation for deleting the too big mote. In other words, I check the size of the upcoming mote. If it's really huge, I delete it (for a cost of 1). If it's not so huge, I almost double my mote (for a cost of 1). Either way, I have a total cost of 1 for each too big mote. What am I missing here?

Comment: Have a look at the example I have where you are size 2 and you're trying to capture a mote of size 1000. How many operations would you need to increase your motes size compared to just deleting the remaining motes.

Comment: Thinking about it more... You don't really need to do path finding. You just need to work out if the number of operations to increase your size sufficiently is less than the remaining number of motes.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to @br3nt answer lets consider this:

if i were to add a **Simple Greedy** solution to your algorithm it'll be a check that if

```
if (sizes[j] < size) {
    // ...
else {
    deleteMote(j);
}
```

whereas `deleteMote(j)`  will do exactly as its name implies and delete the mote whenever more than one step(addition of a mote) is required to grow large enough to eat the mote at index J.

this may not be the perfect solution but that's the first step towards your goal.

Comment: Nope, I'm counting "ops" in scope. I don't want to increment my operations every time I encounter a new mote, only when it's too big. For instance, if I have motes [2, 3, 5] and my initial size is 6, I don't need any new operations to absorb the rest of the motes.

Comment: Ah, i assumed that eating a mote is also an operation